# Best practices for "search data class" in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm hoping this isn't too subjective, but I'm new to ASP.NET MVC and I'm trying to figure out how others may have solved similar problems.

Basically, I have two entities, Customers and Orders.  A customer has many orders; an order belongs to exactly one customer.  I'm making an Order Search feature that should allow a user to search for orders based on order **or** customer information.  Pretty straightforward, I think.

I've read in other posts that the search controller should use GET, but I think it makes more sense to use POST because of the large number of search params.

I'm using Entity Framework to create my models, and that's in a separate class library project and namespace.

[This article](http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2009/04/27/6-tips-for-asp-net-mvc-model-binding.aspx) talks about using binding instead of Request.Form to get at the POST data.  Would it make decent sense to make a class to hold all the search data that could be materialized by the magic model binding?  Otherwise I'd just be poking through the FormCollection to pull out particular values, which might be fine.  Where would you recommend making such a class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is only a partial answer, specifically to the "FormCollection vs Class" part. It's my opinion that you should always use a class for this unless you have a very good reason not to. You get compile-time checking here which is the #1 benefit. You also get Intellisense support which is helpful too. Lastly, you might get some performance benefits as there is potentially less casting/parsing done by your code.

For the GET vs POST question, I'm still struggling with that general question myself but I do have an opinion on your specific use of it. Currently, I'm leaning towards the following rules:

- Use GET if the parameters identify an `entity` of some sort (i.e. ~/product/id/54 = a can of Coke)
- Use POST if the parameters help generate a truly dynamic page where an ungodly number of such pages can exist (a search results screen being an example where there is nearly an infinite number of possibilities).

Now I may be way off with my GET vs POST opinion here, but I think there will be a lot of agreement on the class vs FormCollection opinion.

Comment: Cool, those are the conclusions I reached also.  Is there a "standard" place for me to put that search data class?  Maybe a file in Models?  My "data" class library is shared by other non-MVC projects, so I'm not sure about putting it elsewhere.

Comment: Here you would use a ViewModel to hold that data. Logically, a ViewModel is between a Controller and a Model so you end up with a View -> Controller -> ViewModel -> Model route of communication. The NerdDinner app/tutorial puts the ViewModels in with the Controllers but I don't feel that's the correct place. I think they should deserve their own folder. Again, though, I am not an authoritative source for this sort of thing. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Use a class to encapsulate the search criteria. You can make this a property of your model and then use standard model binding. That way you can pass a single object to your search method, which is much neater and more extensible than having lots of parameters.